# Reorder array to remove upper level 0 index

Tags: php, arrays

I'm wanting to know how I can reindex my array that has a upper level index [0]

My array looks like this

```
$test = array(
   [0] => array(
      id = 1
   )
)
```

What I want is

```
$test = array(
      id = 1
)
```

I know that I can do a foreach to get what I want, but wondering is there a function that does the samething.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it with the example you gave:

```
$test = $test[0];
```

If your problem is more complex, tell us more.

Comment: I'm sorry it worked had some code that wasn't suppose to be there. I'll except the answer as soon as it lets me.